# XNA Resources error

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to figure out tile collision and I cant get this to work. When I collide with the tile, nothing happens.

My collision class

```
    public Point WorldToMapCell(Point worldPoint)
    {
        return new Point((int)worldPoint.X, (int)worldPoint.Y);
    }

    public MapCell GetCellAtWorldPoint(Point worldPoint)
    {
        Point mapPoint = WorldToMapCell(worldPoint);
        return Rows[mapPoint.Y].Columns[mapPoint.X];
    }

    public MapCell GetCellAtWorldPoint(Vector2 worldPoint)
    {
        return GetCellAtWorldPoint(new Point((int)worldPoint.X, (int)worldPoint.Y));
    }
```

my update method

```
        if (myMap.GetCellAtWorldPoint(player.position).Walkable == false)
        {
            player.velocity = Vector2.Zero;
        }
```

Comment: Your WorldToMapCell() function does nothing.  It just returns the same Point object that you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know what kind of game you are working on.

But do you really need to check the position on the map? Or a solution with the [collision_2d_perpixel method](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel) would not be better?

If the collision 2D method is not the good one, can you be more expecite about your collision class?
Where is your reference map? When do you have to say "I'm colliding?"

Can you have a look to this link [dreamincode user problem](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/167529-xna-tile-collision-detection/) and tell us if this is not what you are looking for?

Or you can even have a look to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203893.aspx)